Why can the Product Property of Square Roots be applied when exactly one of the radicands is negative?
Generally, the property $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}$ is stated to only apply when $a,b \ge 0$.
This is because if $a,b \lt 0$, then we would run into situations like $\sqrt{-2}\cdot\sqrt{-2}=\sqrt{-2\cdot-2}=\sqrt{4}=2$, which does not align with the requirement that $(\sqrt{-2})^2=-2$.
However, when we're introduced to taking the square roots of negative numbers, like $\sqrt{-9}$, we're often told that we can rewrite it as the product as $\sqrt{-1}\sqrt{9}=i\cdot3=3i$.
Why are we allowed to still apply the Product Property of Square Roots when exactly one of the radicands is negative?

We are not really allowed to do this. For real numbers $a\geq 0$, $\sqrt{a}$ is by definition the unique non negative square root. It is unique, so no confusion can be made. But as for complex numbers, it's not clear which of the two roots you choose every time. You have to specify which one you choose. (which is why the product rule makes no sense now) So this $i=\sqrt{-1}$ is more of a handwavy notation, which makes sense to use when you first introduce complex numbers to someone. But truth is, $(3i)^2=-9$, and so $3i$ is a (but not "the") square root of $-9$. (and $-3i$ is the other one)

What is $\sqrt{-4}$? Before which, what is $\sqrt{4}$? Why did we choose $+2$, but not $-2$? Because, we had a convention that although there are two numbers satisfying $x^2=4$, by $\sqrt{}$ function, we set a convention that positive should be chosen.
Now, which numbers satisfy $x^2=-4$. There are exactly, of course, two numbers. $\pm 2i$. Which one you prefer now?
Now, you can set a convention. Before which, you must be aware of the fact that any complex number $z$ can be expressed as $z=re^{i\theta}$, which is called the polar form, where $r$ is the modulus of $z$ and $\theta$, which for time being I restrict to $(-\pi, \pi]$ is called argument which is the angle which the line joining $z$ and Origin makes with the $x$ - axis.
Now, the equation $x^2 = re^{i\theta}$ has got two roots, namely $\pm r^{1/2}e^{i\theta/2}$. Among these, pick $+r^{1/2}e^{i\theta/2}$ as the square root of $z$ (Call it the principal value for the sake of distinction. Hence, by $\sqrt{}$ symbol now, set a convention to choose the principal value. For more information, see what are called 'branch cuts').
Thus, as, $z=-4 = 4e^{i\pi}$, $\sqrt{-4} = 4^{1/2}e^{i\pi/2} = 2i$ as $e^{i\pi/2} =i$. Now, with this convention, you must be able to reason out why $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$ if one of them is positive (keeping the definition of Principal value of square root in mind).
As an exercise, try to find the square root (Principal) of $-i$.

For an additional exercise, find the principal square root of $-i$ when the principal value of the argument of any complex number is in $[0,2\pi)$ instead of $(-\pi,\pi]$.

May I know why?

Do you mean, why is that a good exercise? Because it gives a different answer, showing that it matters how we define the principal argument.

Oh okay. Understood. You are right.

This not so much has to do with calculation within $\mathbb R$, rather with calculation within $\mathbb C$. Consider polar coordinates within the Argand plane:
$$(\pm\sqrt z)^2 = (\pm\sqrt{r\,e^{i\phi}})^2 = (\pm\sqrt r\,e^{i\phi/2})^2 = (\pm 1)^2\,(\sqrt r)^2\,(e^{i\phi/2})^2 = r\,e^{i\phi} = z$$
This clearly applies for all values $\phi$. On the other hand you clearly have $2\pi$ periodicity. Thus convention would rather restrict to a single specific $2\pi$ interval. But then, whenever $\phi/2>\pi$, you clearly would get from squaring a value $\phi>2\pi$, which no longer would be within the chosen interval. Thence you would have to rescue to modulo $2\pi$ instead.
--- rk
